# Adding a column from a dataframe to a SpatialPolygon Dataframe

Tags: r, statistics, mapping, geography, tmap

I've been trying to add a column of numerical data from a dataframe to a `SpatialPolygon` dataframe but every attempt leads to the latter dataframe being converted to a standard dataframe similar to the former. I needed to add the column so that I can create a choropleth map with the column's variable as the focus. Obviously the standard dataframe is no good since I'm trying to create a map using `tmap`.

This is how I've been trying to add the column (where `shapefilecomb` is the spatial dataframe and `wardturnout` is the variable containing the column in question):

```
shapefilecomb <- c(wardturnout)
```

Comment: Try 'shapefilecomb$wardturnout <- wardturnout'

Comment: @mdsumner Thanks this worked in terms of adding the column, but now when I try to run 'tm_shape(shapefilecomb) + tm_fill("turnout")'
  i get the error 'Error: Fill argument neither colors nor valid variable name(s)'. the "turnout" variable contains the numerical data I want to be mapped onto the chloropleth. Any ideas?

Comment: I used "wardturnout", make sure the names are consistent

Answer (score 6):

Adding a column into data slot of SpatialPolygonsDataFrame by assignment operator `shapefilecomb$wardturnout <- wardturnout` works, but it is not the safest way to do the job. It relies only on position (first data item goes to first polygon, second to second and so on). It can get messy.

It is best reserved for calculated fields - the `shapefile$valuepercapita <- shapefile$value / shapefile$population` kind of assignment.

For data from external sources it is much better idea to assign value by key. Function `append_data` from `tmap` package does it very nicely, and gives you a message not only when error occurs, but also confirmation when all data was matched perfectly (which I found as a nice touch when working with large sets of imperfect data).

`outShape <- append_data(srcShape, frmData, key.shp = "KOD_LAU1", key.data = "LAU1")`

**Edit (as of 9/2019):** This answer seems to be still going strong... The world has changed though.

1. `tmap::append_data()` has been moved to `tmaptools::append_data()`
   and is by now deprecated
2. `sf` has replaced `sp` as the go-to package in spatial data in R

In
    the `sf` world spatial data are stored in modified `data.frames`, and the
    most appropriate way to assign data items by key is one of the
    `*_join()` functions from `dplyr` - either `dplyr::left_join()` to be
    on safe side, or `dplyr::inner_join()` if filtering on both sides is actually desired behavior.